# How to send SMS to mobiles using Sms functionality in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sms, ionic4

```
  this.sms.send(9191919191, 'Hi this is dummy msg')
      .then(() => {
        alert('The Message is sent');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('The Message is Failed', error);
        alert('Error:-  ' + error);
      });
```

I need to send SMS to the respective mobile number but when I run the application it shows user denied your permission error hoe to solve this problem please help me

Comment: You can provide more information, ionic version, etc?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms  I worked using this documentation I'm facing problem even after providing permissions too

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms) the phone number should be in single quotation marks, try this:

```
this.sms.send('9191919191', 'Hi this is dummy msg')
      .then(() => {
        alert('The Message is sent');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('The Message is Failed', error);
        alert('Error:-  ' + error);
      });
```

Don't forget to inject in your constructor: `constructor(private sms: SMS) { }`

Comment: Yes, I Changed Phone number 9191919191 to '9191919191' even after that also its won't work and I added permissions too.

Comment: Can you give us the log?

Comment: There is no log to provide because I'm using it in Mobile getting error in alert message format so that I'm getting hasPermission Error. I need to show sample code that i changed but it's possilbe here.. how can i contact you

Comment: You can get the log by using Logcat on AndroidStudio

Comment: But I'm using Ionic 4 + Angular in VS Code there we didn't get any logcat right?